# Parsing Error The Keyword import is Reserved (SublimeLinter-contrib-eslint)

Tags: javascript, parsing, sublimetext, eslint

I have a problem with eslint, it gives me [Parsing Error The keyword import is reserve] this is only  occur in sublime, in atom editor  work well. I have eslint

.eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
    "extends": "airbnb",
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ]
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "paint",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "paint on the browser",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "paint",
    "javascript"
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^11.2.0",
    "eslint": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^2.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^3.11.2",
    "gulp-babel": "^5.2.1",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.1",
    "gulp-stylus": "^2.2.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem was i had installed eslint globally and locally, causing inconsistencies in SublimeLinter-contrib-eslint. I uninstalled eslint globally and SublimeLinter is working.

Comment: Thanks for this.  IMO this problem may more universal that just SublimeLinter.

Comment: Stems from module-type syntax. CommonJS module uses 'require'.

Answer (score 250):

Add this to the root of your `.eslintrc.json` (formerly `.eslintrc`)

```
"parser": "babel-eslint"
```

and make sure to run:

```
npm install babel-eslint --save-dev
```

Comment: This worked for me too, thanks.  If it helps anyone, my entire .eslint file is `{"parser": "babel-eslint"}`

Comment: For me, the file had to be _renamed_ to `.eslintrc` with its contents `{"parser" : "babel-eslint"}` 

Comment: No need to change the parser. Doing `"parserOptions": { "sourceType": "module" }` is enough

Comment: @nathancahill Thanks. But are there other more general benefits of babel-eslint?

Comment: `{ "parser": "babel-eslint" }` worked for me with TypeScript and Gatsby in the `gatsby-browser` file 

Comment: As of July-2021, { "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser" }

Comment: But why does adding `babel-eslint` work? Just setting parseOptions/sourceType to "module" is not enough according to what I experience.

Comment: sourceType 'module' is not supported when ecmaVersion < 2015. Adding `"ecmaVersion": 6`
 may be also necessary.

Comment: `"ecmaVersion": "latest" ` was helpful for me -- though probably not suited for all.

Answer (score 108):

The eslint option that solves the "The keyword import is reserved" error is `parserOptions.sourceType`. Setting it to `"module"` allows the `import` keyword to be used.

.eslintrc

```
{
    "parserOptions": {
        "sourceType": "module"
    }
}
```

**Docs:** https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser-options

Comment: Additionally, although I do not use babel, `npm install babel-eslint --save-dev` and `parser: 'babel-eslint'` were needed to get rid of the 'import is reserved' error. It is [not a good solution](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/11189#issuecomment-446646882) but a workaround [recommended by eslint for now](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/11486).

Comment: Yes, but I also had to add `"ecmaVersion": "latest"` under `parserOptions`.

Answer (score 15):

Closing VS code and re-open it does the trick for me...

Comment: The same solved the problem with WebStorm

Answer (score 9):

Not sure about it but try to rename your file to *.eslintrc* and just use

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "plugins": ["react"]
};
```

Also be sure you have the required packages installed.
[github.com/airbnb/javascript](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/linters)

Comment: I solved the error, the problem was i had eslint globally and locally. Thanks

Comment: Oddly the `.eslintrc.js` to `.eslintrc` fixed it for me, weird. Thanks!

Comment: jfyi - This din't work for VS Code, with or without global eslint installation.

Comment: I spent a while on this before realizing that I'd named my file `eslintrc.js` and not `.eslintrc.js` (no leading dot).

Comment: Renaming `.eslintrc.js` to `.eslintrc.cjs` worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

The [currently highest voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41190209) works.
However,  it is no longer under maintenance and the newly suggested approach is to use the version from the mono repo instead.

**Installation**

```
$ npm install eslint @babel/core @babel/eslint-parser --save-dev
# or
$ yarn add eslint @babel/core @babel/eslint-parser -D
```

**.eslintrc.js**

```
module.exports = {
  parser: "@babel/eslint-parser",
};
```

[Reference](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/eslint/babel-eslint-parser#usage)

Answer (score 3):

i also got this error in a meteor project and i could solved it setting sourceType to "module"
more details can be found in Eslint docs:
http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser-options

Comment: jfyi - This din't work for VS Code, copy pasted in parserOptions > sourceType.

Answer (score 3):

This config worked for me. (I am using **create-react-app** but applicable to any eslint project)

---

`.eslintrc (create file in root if it doesnt exist)`

```
{
    "rules": {
      "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": [ "error", {
        "components": [ "Link" ],
        "specialLink": [ "to" ]
      }]
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaVersion": 2015
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The same issue occurred when creating `js` files within a typescript react-native project while eslint is enabled.

Changing the file type from `js` to `ts` resolved the issue.

Also, adding the .eslintrc.js file as mentioned in previous answers resolved the issue without changing the file type from `js` to `ts`.

```js
       module.exports = {
          parser: "@babel/eslint-parser",
       };
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is seen with the new react app, and in Visual Studio Code, even at this time - August 2022

Create a file `.eslintrc.js` in the root folder
Paste the below contents in `.eslintrc.js`
Restart your editor, like VS Code.
Now I can see real errors, instead of those fake import/export errors.
`.eslintrc.js` file contents:

```
   export const parser = "@babel/eslint-parser";
```

The accepted answer works, however, the newly suggested approach is to use the version from  ES6.

Answer (score 1):

I found this issue while creating the vue project (Used Editor: Visual Code)

Install babel-eslint package

> npm install babel-eslint

Create the `.eslintrc.js` file and add below code

```
module.exports = {
    root: true,
    parserOptions: {
        'sourceType': 'module',
        parser: 'babel-eslint'   
    }
}
```

`npm run serve`, that error will be resolved like magic.

Comment: OR, try without 'sourceType' module.exports = { root: true, parserOptions: { parser: 'babel-eslint'
} }

Answer (score 1):

Adding ecmaVersion to .eslintrc.json fixed the issue

```
{
    "ecmaVersion": 2015,
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ESlint the disabling rules in .eslintrc.json file.

```
  {
  "extends": "next",
  "rules": {
    "react/no-unescaped-entities": "off",
    "@next/next/no-page-custom-font": "off"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been facing this error on next.js 13 today and my eslint file looks like this:

```
{
  "root": true,
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "version": "detect"
    },
    "env": {
      "browser": true,
      "node": true,
      "es2020": true,
      "jest": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "eslint:recommended",
      "plugin:react/recommended",
      "plugin:react-hooks/recommended",
      "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
      "plugin:prettier/recommended"
    ],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": "latest",
      "sourceType": "module",
      "ecmaFeatures": {
        "jsx": true
      }
    },
    "plugins": ["react", "react-hooks", "@typescript-eslint"],
    "rules": {}
  }
}
```

So I removed this piece of code and it works fine:

```
"settings": {
        "react": {
          "version": "detect"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me VSCode the eslint extension had a problem and after disabling it for current workspace it worked