# trying to build rollup + babel + react starter, but get error during the building

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, rollup

I am getting an "Unexpected token" error message when I am running my rollup build script.

[image: Error: Unexpected token rollup]

Here is the GitHub link : https://github.com/mxm-web-develop/issues

It seems that babel didn't translate the JSX during building, so I got [!] Error: Unexpected token

Comment: That link is no longer valid so there's no detail available for anyone else

Answer (score 3):

I cloned your repo and it seems there are several things wrong with your setup.

1. Typo in [babel.config.js](https://github.com/mxm-web-develop/issues/blob/main/babel.config.js). Remove the extra comma.

Change this:

```
presets: [require("@babel/preset-env"), , require("@babel/preset-react")],
```

To this:

```
presets: [
  require("@babel/preset-env"), 
  require("@babel/preset-react"),
],
```

2. Typo in [rollup.config.js](https://github.com/mxm-web-develop/issues/blob/main/rollup.config.js):

Change this:

```
pulugs:[ ... ],
```

To this:

```
plugins:[ ... ],
```

3. Having corrected these two errors, I ran `npm run build:rollup` and got the message "No ESLint configuration found", so I added the following to `package.json`:

```
"eslintConfig": {},
```

4. I then ran `npm run build:rollup` again and got the next error message: "Parsing error: The keyword 'import' is reserved". To fix this, install [babel-eslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-eslint) (`npm install babel-eslint --save-dev`) and adjust the `eslintConfig` in `package.json` as follows:

```
"eslintConfig": {
  "parser": "babel-eslint"
},
```

See here for more details: [Parsing Error The Keyword import is Reserved (SublimeLinter-contrib-eslint)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36002226/parsing-error-the-keyword-import-is-reserved-sublimelinter-contrib-eslint)

5. I then ran `npm run build:rollup` again and saw yet another error message: "Invalid value for option "output.dir" - you must set either "output.file" for a single-file build or "output.dir" when generating multiple chunks."

Looking at your rollup config, you have this:

```
output:{
  dir:pkg.main,
  file:'index.js',
  format:'es',
  name:appName
},
```

You need to remove either the `dir` or `file` key. I removed the `dir` key, giving me this:

```
output:{
  file:'index.js',
  format:'es',
  name:appName
},
```

Now when I ran `npm run build:rollup`, the bundle was created in the project root, as specified in your rollup config.

I appreciate that you have made a slimmed down version of the problem you are experiencing, so you might not need to follow all of the steps I have posted above.

HTH

Comment: Deserves an upvote just for the effort! Annoyingly the repo is no longer live